# Moving PBI from one sprint to the next with a mixture of task states

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I use Visual Studio Team Services (was TFS Online).

When I move a PBI from one sprint to another and there are a mixture of completed and uncompleted tasks, only the uncompleted tasks are moved to the next sprint.

My manager wants all of the tasks to move forward with the PBI regardless of state.

Two questions:

1. Is this the expected behavior?
2. How can I make it do what my boss is wanting without having to
   manually go in and adjust the iteration path on completed tasks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's expected behavior. You completed those tasks within a certain sprint -- in terms of capacity planning and historical reporting, that's time spent regardless of whether the parent PBI was completed or not. Moving the tasks elsewhere would mess with that.

There's no way that I know of to alter that behavior, but you could write an [extension](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/extensions/overview) to implement it. I wouldn't recommend it. If you're commonly having issues completing PBIs in a sprint, you probably need to adjust the team's velocity accordingly or attempt to improve your estimates, since you're either overcommitting or underestimating, or some combination of the two.